# Horizontal Bar wont show in Firefox 12 and above

Tags: css, firefox, horizontal-scrolling

I've just noticed that Firefox 12 and 13 won't show horizontal bar when the page gets x overflow. I tried to make CSS declaration:

```
html {
overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
```

but it doesn't help.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You mean they won't show an horizontal bar on your specific page, I suppose. Can your reduce your example and make a jsfiddle ?

Comment: is this working on other browsers for you?

Comment: overflow-x: scroll works for me in FF12. You might have committed some other mistake.

Comment: Hi mates! 
@dystroy: yes, let's say my page is 1100px. If i resize my page, i cant get horizontal scroll bar (Only occur when using FF12 and 13)

Comment: @Jacxel: yes, works well on other browsers and on FF below version 12

Comment: @Ankit: Yeah i saw that solution from other thread but it doesnt work for me. I also checked the DOM for any override css declarations but there's none

Comment: The problem being on your specific page, we cannot help without more. Please use this to help us help you : http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line in the jquery-ui style sheet that causes this is:

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { .position: absolute; left: -99999999px; }
```

If you change it to the following you should see your scrollbars again:

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible { /*.position: absolute; */ left: -99999999px; }
```

Although I have no clue what so ever what other effects this change might have. I don't know what that element is used for.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for this! The page has horizontal scrollbar now :)

Comment: A override `body .ui-helper-hidden-accessible { position: fixed }` works to me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not made a mistake elsewhere, try it in another browser first to make sure then strip all the CSS and just replace it with `html {
overflow-x: scroll !important;
}` and see if it works, if you did anything with changing the width of the page it would change the effect on the page.

I assume, that there is actually some overflow to display?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. Page looks fine in chrome, IE and FF11. I can make it go away by disabling http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css (via WebDeveloper toolbar). Can't find a root cause yet though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to do this...
    .ui-helper-hidden-accessible { /*.position: absolute; */ left: -99999999px; }
this will cause these elements to show on screen, when they are supposed to be positioned off to the left. As these elements probably don't always exist you'll be putting a "bug in the bank" for later on, one day you'll get a load of elements showing up on your site that should be invisible. Which will be really hard to debug!

This issue looks like it might be related to this https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=749935 large number issue, you could try reducing the size of the number (-99999999)?